# FLV MetaData Injection

Tags: flv

I was wondering if there was a sever side system for injecting metaData into FLVs recorded using a streaming server like Red5.  I don't want to hack in a command line injector, I would like to use a .Net, CF or Java solution.

Caveat: I know that Red5 has its own Metadata.xml, I want to inject metaData directly into the FLV.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to use flvedit by Marc-André Lafortune! Its written in Ruby and works awesome!

Indeed its a command-line-tool but the only thing you have to do is something like:

"flvedit myawesomefile.flv --update --save thenameoftheflvfilewithmetadata.flv"

;)

Here is the link:

http://github.com/marcandre/flvedit/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I need make my server side app to inject metadata to flv as well. I found this [jflvtool](https://code.google.com/p/jflvtool/). I wonder if anyone here had used this extensively and has anyfeedback on how mature the project is.